# How can I append to bootstrap popover options for specific content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, popover

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G6yRk/

I'd like to load general options for all popovers and then override specific options per id as necessary.

For example:

```
<span id="specificPopover" class="popoverThis">hover me</span>
```

with

```
$("[rel='popover'], .popoverThis").popover({html:true});
$("#specificPopover").popover({title:'title',content:'<em>content</em>'});
```

But this doesn't work.  What am I missing?

Comment: Do you mean like this: http://jsfiddle.net/G6yRk/1/

Comment: Interesting.  So it just has to be reversed?  Any clue what's going on there?  Submit as answer and you win! ;)